# Aurora Serverless v2 reader doesn't seem to scale independently

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

What could be the problem of the reader instance not showing in Cloudwatch that it uses less capacity than the writer? (tried all the solutions from the AWS documentation)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the following documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2-administration.html#aurora-serverless-v2-choosing-promotion-tier

You have to set the promotion tier of the reader ( or of all instances to > 2). Otherwise the reader will be always on the same tier as the writer as the reader should be prepared to become the Writer in case of failover.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in the screenshot reader is set to tier-15, so theoretically it should scale independently.